# localStorage resets on Chrome after getItem, setItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to save data in localStorage with jQuery. The data I am trying to save resets every time I refresh my Chrome browser. First, I retrieve the data from a dictionary through `getItem`, then I set it using `setItem`. Sounds pretty simple, but I can't get it to save. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here's my js:

```
moneylove = {"snacks":{"c":1,"m":1,"e":2},"food":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":1},"soap":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":0},"toys":{"c":2,"m":1,"e":2}} //dog state
for (state in moneylove["snacks"]){
    stateadd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(state))
    stateadd += moneylove["snacks"][state]
    localStorage.setItem(state,JSON.stringify(stateadd))
}
console.log(localStorage)
```

Comment: Do you set `localStorage` before `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Are the browser developer tool showing the local storage data after setItem?

Answer (score 1):

You replace the `key`s because the each sub-object has same properties so that it replaces anyway. Change to be like this.

```
var moneylove = {"snacks":{"c":1,"m":1,"e":2},"food":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":1},"soap":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":0},"toys":{"c":2,"m":1,"e":2}} //dog state
for (state in moneylove["snacks"]){
    stateadd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(state))
    stateadd += moneylove["snacks"][state]
    localStorage.setItem("snacks" + state,JSON.stringify(stateadd)) // Make key be unique.
}
console.log(localStorage)
```

**EDIT**

The complete calculation and storage method as following example. This can calculate the states in each object in `moneylove`.

```
var moneylove = {"snacks":{"c":1,"m":1,"e":2},"food":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":1},"soap":{"c":2,"m":0,"e":0},"toys":{"c":2,"m":1,"e":2}} //dog state

for(var itemKey in moneylove) {
  var item = moneylove[itemKey];
  for (var stateKey in item){
    var storageKey = itemKey + "-" + stateKey;
    var stateadd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || '0')
    stateadd += item[stateKey];
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(stateadd)) // Make key be unique.
  }
}
console.log(localStorage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
var DB = function(){
    this.Read = function(index){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage[index]).data;
    };

    this.Write = function(index, data){
        localStorage[index] = JSON.stringify({data : data});
    };

    this.Test = function(){ // test support localStorage!
        return typeof localStorage == typeof {};
    };

    this.Clear = function(index){
      if(typeof index === "undefined"){
        localStorage = {};
      } else {
        localStorage[index] = JSON.stringify({data : []});
      }
    };
}

// example:
var x = new DB(); // new data base
if(!x.Test()) alert('Error!'); // not support!
x.Write('food', ['food','bar','google']); // write data
console.log(x.Read('food')); // get data!

x.Clear('food'); // clear data!
console.log(x.Read('food')); // get data!
```